# display button only when page loads completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="product_197_submit_button" class="wpsc_buy_button" name="Buy" value="Add To Cart">
```

Now the thing is that if user clicks button before all scripts are loaded -> I get error in shopping cart. Is there a way to disable clicking on the button (or hide it from display) UNTIL complete page is loaded into users browser ?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hide it through css and then show it when page loads.

Css

```
.wpsc_buy_button{
   display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#product_197_submit_button").show();
});
```

Alernatively you can disable the button by default and then enable in on page load. Try this.

Markup change

```
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="product_197_submit_button" 
class="wpsc_buy_button" name="Buy" value="Add To Cart">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#product_197_submit_button").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: 4 second difference! You win this round @ShankarSangoli! +1

Comment: I personally prefer disabling and then enabling over show and hide.

Comment: @SKS - Even I agree with you, it makes UI look more elegant. Edited my answer with alternative approach.

Comment: I've tried bot your methods but tried to use class instead of ID
    $(".wpsc_buy_button").show();
and it's not working ?

Comment: @Peter - Are you sure the class name is correct? If you are hiding it through css then `$(".wpsc_buy_button").show()` makes sense. If you are setting `disabled` property the use `$(".wpsc_buy_button").prop('disabled', false)`

Comment: I'm using this and it does hide the button but it never shows it `<style>
.wpsc_buy_button {display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wpsc_buy_button").show();
});
</script>`

Comment: Try this `$(".wpsc_buy_button").css('display', 'block');`

Comment: Thanks - got it sorted out now :)

Answer (score 3):

Disable the button by default,

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="submit" id="product_197_submit_button"
```

and then enabled it when your dom is ready:

```
$(function() {
    $("#product_197_submit_button").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#product_197_submit_button').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.wpsc_buy_button").hide(); // unless you can use CSS
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("input.wpsc_buy_button").show();
});
```

If you want to wait for all the images to load rather than just the DOM use

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

rahtner than

```
$("document").ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$(document).ready();` in this case because that is being executed when the document is loaded.
`$(window).load();` is more recommended as that is being executed when the page is completely loaded (including images).

**EDIT** Just read that it's only about scripts being loaded, which in this case it's perfectly fine to use `$(document).read();`